# Missing key in messageheader in activeMq

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

The message can be successfully sent to ActiveMq. When checking in the activeMq webconsole for the message, only key1 and key4 can be found in the "Properties" table(supposed it's the messageheader), key2 and key3 are missed.

What caused it? any idea?

```
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage;

@Autowired
MessageChannel msgChannel;

...
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("key1", "value1");
headers.put("key2", Utils.StrToDate("20120531", "yyyyMMdd"));
//FileWorkInfo is inmutable and implemented Serializable
headers.put("key3", new FileWorkInfo("abc.txt"));
headers.put("key4", 3);
MessageHeaders msgheader = new MessageHeaders(headers);
GenericMessage<String> msg = new GenericMessage("Test", msgheader);
//the msg has all the expected keys in header here
msgChannel.send (msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS javadoc states:

Property values can be boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double, and String.

Presumably, activemq silently drops non-compliant values.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between headers in your example is that "key2" and "key3" require serialization. I see 3 possibilities here:

1. Spring Integration does not send headers
2. AMQ does not accept/drops headers
3. AMQ console does not show headers if they are stream of bytes rather than String/primitives

I would try to eliminate possibilities one by one by enabling the logging on the SI level first to ensure that headers are being sent. Then I would log the incoming message in a simple client (e.g. using the "wire-tap" to logging adapter in SI) to ensure that headers are being received. If first is true but second is false the issue would be somewhere on the broker level. In this case you would have two options - try and figure out AMQ issue or use String header value instead of serializable one. This will not exactly be the same approach but it will allow you to achieve the same result.